# How to display a form filed with size and maxlength attributes in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I have a model form that contains a DecimalField() with max_digits set to 5. How do I display this field this way:

```
<input type"text" size="5" maxlength="5" />
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    myfield = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':5, 'maxlength':5})
```

Read the [forms documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/forms/).